# Use value of variable as object name in Python

Tags: python, class, object, oop

I have a class called Order that basically just creates all of the parameters as instance objects (for now). There is a class variable called order_num which is the number of orders (increases when each object is created). I want the name of each object created to be the number of orders plus one. I have a variable `next_order_num` for that. I need to have the name of the object being created as the numerical value for `next_order_num`. How would you recommend doing that?

Here is the code:

```
next_order_num = Order.order_count + 1

O1 = Order(next_order_num, '10/10/22', 1000, 1000, 275, '1234 street road, 12345', 25, False)
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you mean you want `order1 = Order(1, ...)`, `order2 = Order(2, ...)`, etc. I would recommend storing the orders in a list instead and storing the order number in the `Order` itself.  Please clarify since `1` isn't a valid object name in your example.  What do you mean by "creates all parameters as instance objects"?

Comment: A variable name must be a valid identifier but a number isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in python can start with a number. You could keep two lists one of numbers and the other with the order instances. This way you can use the order number as an index for the second list.

```
order_nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# These would be real orders not strings
orders = ["order1", "order2", "order3", "order4", "order5",
          "order6", "order7", "order8", "order9", "order10", ]

for i in range(len(order_nums)):
    print(orders[i])
```